# Resource to learn modelisation of quantum measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, measurements, models

I need to learn how we do model quantum measurement (for experiments for example).

If we study a quantum system X, when we measure it we usually consider a projective measurement (so we use the postulate of quantum mechanics to be able to predict the state after measurement with associate probabilities).

But we can go a step further by modelling the process of measurement by a Hamiltonian of interaction between the quantum system and the measurement device.

I would like to learn more about this kind of things. I hope my question is clear enough, if not don't hesitate to tell me.

I would prefer a book to learn it, but if there are nice article explaining I can take those as well. I just would like a clear resource (in general books are more clear than article from my perspective, this is why I would prefer a textbook).

Comment: This paper and many of the references model measurement with quantum mechanics https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245